# Failed to load a library: cairo

Tags: python, python-3.x, weasyprint

I keep getting this error when trying to run the following command:

```
python -m weasyprint http://weasyprint.org weasyprint.pdf
```

The error:

```
  raise OSError("dlopen() failed to load a library: %s" % ' / '.join(names))
OSError: dlopen() failed to load a library: cairo / cairo-2 / cairo-gobject-2 / cairo.so.2
```

I installed Weasyprint using `pip install weasyprint`. To install cairo i used this doc: https://weasyprint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html

But, at the end of the guide, when i try to run `WHERE libcairo-2.dll` i get a `not found` error.

I have been following the guide step by step but it's not working and i keep getting the same error, i searched for various solutions but none of them fixes the issue. Any advice? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8):

You need to also install the GTK+ libraries (not just weasyprint), in order for weasyprint to render the final PDF.

You can find the installation instructions for your OS [documented on weasyprint's website](https://weasyprint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html#windows).

> Dear Windows user, please follow these steps carefully.
>
> Really carefully. Don’t cheat.
>
> Besides a proper Python installation and a few Python packages,
>   WeasyPrint needs the Pango, cairo and GDK-PixBuf libraries. They are
>   required for the graphical stuff: Text and image rendering. These
>   libraries aren’t Python packages. They are part of GTK+ (formerly
>   known as GIMP Toolkit), **and must be installed separately**.

If you're running a 64bit version of windows you can grab the GTK installers from [here](https://github.com/tschoonj/GTK-for-Windows-Runtime-Environment-Installer). 
Once you have that installed... Then running

```
python -m weasyprint http://weasyprint.org weasyprint.pdf
```

Should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

macOS Monterey, I resolved it by just `brew install pango` and it seems to install all the necessary dependencies including Cairo that I needed. My lucky day!