# can't import a ".json" file using pyside and python

Tags: python, json, pyside, qt-designer

Good evening, I am developing an application in QtDesigner PySide2 in python, the main code so far is the following:

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QMainWindow
from views.Main_Menu import MainWindow
from Custom_Widgets.Widgets import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication
import sys

class MainMenu_Controller(QMainWindow, MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui=MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        loadJsonStyle(self,self.ui)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window=MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I import the configurations from a ".json" file, which is the following:

```
{
"QMainWindow":[
    {
        "tittle":"Control de Impuestos",
        "icon":":/Iconos/assets/Iconos/framer.svg",
        "frameless":true,
        "transluscentBg":true,
        "sizeGrip":"sizeGrip",
        "navigation":[
            {
                "minimize":"Minimize",
                "close":"Close",
                "restore":[
                    {
                        "buttonName":"Restorebtn",
                        "normalIcon":":/Iconos/assets/Iconos/minimize-2.svg",
                        "maximizedIcon":":/Iconos/assets/Iconos/maximize-2.svg"
                    }
                ],
                "moveWindow":"TopMenuContainer",
                "tittleBar":"TopMenuContainer"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

The problem is that the file runs, but when I import 'Custom_Widgets' it gives me the following error:

```
  `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Marce\Downloads\responsive ui\custom qmenu\main.py", line 18, in <module>
from ui_interface import *
File "C:\Users\Marce\Downloads\responsive ui\env\Lib\site-packages\shiboken2\files.dir\shibokensupport\__feature__.py", line 142, in _import
return original_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
File "c:\Users\Marce\Downloads\responsive ui\custom qmenu\ui_interface.py", line 15, in <module>
from Custom_Widgets.Widgets import QCustomSlideMenu
File "C:\Users\Marce\Downloads\responsive ui\env\Lib\site-packages\shiboken2\files.dir\shibokensupport\__feature__.py", line 142, in _import
return original_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Marce\Downloads\responsive ui\env\lib\site-packages\Custom_Widgets\Widgets.py", line 19, in <module>
from .Qss import SassCompiler
File "C:\Users\Marce\Downloads\responsive ui\env\Lib\site-packages\shiboken2\files.dir\shibokensupport\__feature__.py", line 142, in _import
return original_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Marce\Downloads\responsive ui\env\lib\site-packages\Custom_Widgets\Qss\SassCompiler.py", line 20, in <module>
from . SvgToPngIcons import NewIconsGenerator
File "C:\Users\Marce\Downloads\responsive ui\env\Lib\site-packages\shiboken2\files.dir\shibokensupport\__feature__.py", line 142, in _import
return original_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Marce\Downloads\responsive ui\env\lib\site-packages\Custom_Widgets\Qss\SvgToPngIcons.py", line 1, in <module>
import cairosvg
File "C:\Users\Marce\Downloads\responsive ui\env\Lib\site-packages\shiboken2\files.dir\shibokensupport\__feature__.py", line 142, in _import
return original_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Marce\Downloads\responsive ui\env\lib\site-packages\cairosvg\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
from . import surface  # noqa isort:skip
File "C:\Users\Marce\Downloads\responsive ui\env\Lib\site-packages\shiboken2\files.dir\shibokensupport\__feature__.py", line 142, in _import
return original_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Marce\Downloads\responsive ui\env\lib\site-packages\cairosvg\surface.py", line 9, in <module>
import cairocffi as cairo
File "C:\Users\Marce\Downloads\responsive ui\env\Lib\site-packages\shiboken2\files.dir\shibokensupport\__feature__.py", line 142, in _import
return original_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Marce\Downloads\responsive ui\env\lib\site-packages\cairocffi\__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
cairo = dlopen(
File "C:\Users\Marce\Downloads\responsive ui\env\lib\site-packages\cairocffi\__init__.py", line 45, in dlopen
raise OSError(error_message)  # pragma: no cover
OSError: no library called "cairo-2" was found
no library called "cairo" was found
cannot load library 'C:\Program Files\GTK3-Runtime Win64\bin\libcairo-2.dll': error 0xc1
cannot load library 'libcairo.so.2': error 0x7e
cannot load library 'libcairo.2.dylib': error 0x7e
cannot load library 'libcairo-2.dll': error 0x7e

OSError: no library called "cairo-2" was found
no library called "cairo" was found
no library called "libcairo-2" was found
cannot load library 'libcairo.so.2': error 0x7e
cannot load library 'libcairo.2.dylib': error 0x7e
cannot load library 'libcairo-2.dll': error 0x7e
```

`

Do you know what the problem is? It took several weeks looking for the solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to load a library: cairo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56704202/failed-to-load-a-library-cairo)

Comment: You have `.svg` assets specified in your configuration, and Qt needs a library called `libcairo` to be able to use those types of images. What operating system are you using? You will need to install the cairo libraries (and probably development files).

Comment: I tried with all the indicated options, following all the indications and it still throws me the same error. What else could I try? i am using Windows 10 x64

Comment: Did you install the Cairo binaries using the GTK+ installer for Windows? What version of Python are you using?

Comment: yes, use the GTK+ installer and nothing, update python to the latest version because I read that it could be the problem but it didn't fix it either. I do not know what else to do.